# Correct way of loading non-AMD compatible jQuery plugins in require.js with jQuery in noConflict mode?

Tags: requirejs, amd

Say I want to use jquery together with a standard, non-amd enabled jquery plugin that has been defined using standard closure: `(function($))( $.fn.myplugin = { ... } )(jQuery);` and it all sits inside of a `js/libs/jquery/jquery.myplugin.js`.

I use this config:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'js/',
  paths: {
    'jquery':          'libs/jquery/jquery-noconflict', 
    'underscore':      'libs/underscore/underscore',
    'backbone':        'libs/backbone/backbone',
    'jquery-myplugin': 'libs/jquery/jquery.myplugin'
  },
  shim: {
    'backbone': {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
  },
  'jquery-myplugin': {
    deps:  ['jquery'] 
  }
});
```

I load jQuery in no-conflict mode in `libs/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js`, becase I don't want to pollute global namespace:

```
define(['libs/jquery'], function () {
  return jQuery.noConflict(true);
});
```

and this is how I load my main app.js:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'jquery-myplugin'],
function($, _, Backbone, MyPlugin){
  //MyPlugin is always undefined, not even sure if 
  //I should be passing it here if it only extends jQuery?
});
```

Now, here is the problem I am experiencing - while I can use all libraries defined above without any problems, I could not work out the correct `shim` configuration to load non-AMD enabled jquery plugins.

I've tried setting up `jquery-myplugin` as `deps` of the `jquery` (and other way around) but I could never get it working.

It seems like I'm having problem with the following scenario:

1. jQuery loads in no-conflict mode.
2. plugin code runs, extending the instance of the jQuery above
3. I can use $ within my application, extended by the plugin code, so $.myplugin is available.

I have seen similar questions floating around but none of them actually resolves this issue giving only vague suggestions such as "use shim config"...

**Edit**

I also tried using

```
"jquery-myplugin": {
    deps: ["jquery"],
    exports: "jQuery.fn.myplugin"
}
```

And whilst plugin methods are available once loaded as AMD module this way, I still can't access: `$('.class').myplugin()` as default $ object hasn't been extended with myplugin code.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: module dependencies should be expressed in an array: `define(['dep1',  'dep2'...'depn'], function(dep1, dep2, ...depn){});` as described [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#requireargs)

Comment: good catch, but that was just my mistype on stackoverflow, the underlying issue is still there

Answer (score 3):

Using `jQuery.noConflict(true)` removes the `jQuery` global variable. When your plugin loads, it tries to access `jQuery`, but can't, causing this failure.

If your plugin was a module, it could get access to jQuery as a dependency. Or you could leave `jQuery` available as a global.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I do know what happens here and what I want to do is to use require.js correctly where none of the modules should create a global variable and all other modules load jQuery as dependency if needed.

Comment: If that's the case, you won't be able to use unconverted plugins. If you want jQuery to be available only as a module, then you'll have to convert the plugins to use `define()`, in order to declare a dependency on jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I was under the impression that shim config still allows you to handle non-AMD enabled modules without using global dependencies. IMHO it sucks big time that you have to modify 3rd party code in order to get it working  with AMD/require..

Comment: Shim lets you turn a plain script into a module, but it doesn't let you get at the dependencies. If you leave jQuery as a global, it'll work out. It is a shame that 3rd party stuff doesn't work right with AMD. When jQuery adopted it, I had high hopes. And when Backbone removed it, it became clear that we weren't going to see mass adoption anytime soon.

Answer (score -1):

First, insure that "path/to/jquery-myplugin" actually extends `window.jQuery` and not `$`

noConflict() leaves `window.jQuery` object defined but unbinds itself from `window.$` On some new browsers `window.$` is built in alias for native `document.querySelectorAll` function.

Second, your myplugin does NOT need to return itself, as it cannot be used by itself. Since it **extends** jQuery, return jQuery from myplugin call.

Lastly, "path/to/jquery-myplugin" is NOT a **module**. It's a plain JS file. It's possible RequireJS tries to load it like a module and does not find `define()` call, which leads to mess. Try actually adding ".js" file extension to the reference to signal to RequireJS that it needs to use "js!" plugin to load the resource.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "path/to/jquery",
        "jquery-myplugin": "path/to/jquery-myplugin.js"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery": {
          init: function() {
             return window.jQuery.noConflict();
          },
        "jquery-myplugin": {
          deps: ['jquery']
          init: function($) {
             return $;
          },
       }
    } 
});
```

Comment: That's false. The code for noConflict is here: 

````javascript
noConflict: function( deep ) {
  if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
   window.$ = _$;
  }

  if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
   window.jQuery = _jQuery;
  }

  return jQuery;
 },
````

When you pass the "deep" param it unbinds window.jQuery as well, so you can run multiple versions on the same page.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you today. Here is how I could fix it :

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app": "../app"
    }
});

// Final version of jQuery with all needed plugins.
define("jquery", ["jquery-core", "myplugin"], function(jqCore) {
    return jqCore;
});

// Define core jQuery module.
define("jquery-core", ["jquery-1.9.1.min"], function() {
    return jQuery.noConflict(true);
});

// This module exposes jquery module to the global scope and returns previous defined version.
define("jq-global", ["jquery-core"], function(jqCore) {
    var tmp = jQuery;
    jQuery = jqCore;
    return tmp;
});

// Define your plugin here, and don't forget to reset previous jQuery version.
define("myplugin", ["jq-global", "jquery.myplugin"], function(jqGlobal, jqPlugin) {
    jQuery = jqGlobal;
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

Now in my app/main.js file I can do the following :

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
    $('body').myplugin();
});
```

The idea here is to expose jQuery temporary before plugin code is executed. So far I didn't test the solution in a larger environment with a lot more modules to load, so I can't guarantee it will work in the long term ;)

**Edit**

This solution won't work!! Since requirejs doesn't load the scripts sequentially, it is possible the plugin js file loads before jquery which will cause the execution to fail. Sorry for this.

If someone has another idea...